# Flash movie loads in IE but not Chrome

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome

So I embedded a basic flash movie as per:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html

It loads fine in IE, but the flash player in Chrome cannot load the movie. Flash works fine on other sites in Chrome, so what's wrong with this HTML?

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"
WIDTH="162"
HEIGHT="391"
id="MobileAnimation">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="img/animatedphone.swf">
<PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
<PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#FFFFFF>
<EMBED href="img/animatedphone.swf"
quality=high
bgcolor=#FFFFFF
WIDTH="162"
HEIGHT="391"
NAME="MobileAnimation"
ALIGN=""
TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"
PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</EMBED></OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that reads:

```
<EMBED href="img/animatedphone.swf"
```

Should be:

```
<EMBED src="img/animatedphone.swf"
```

Note the change from `href` to `src`.